# Single angular js directive and many controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to know how to invoke a function residing in controller on the ng-click event of template element. I have to use this directive in many pages.Hence I need to handle the click event in respective controller pages.The below code invokes the click function (moreitemdetails) residing within the directive.I tried setting the scope as `moreitemdetails: '='` . It is also  not working.

I have been using the directive

```
app.directive('groceryList', function){

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            array: '=',
            listItemClick:'&',
            moreitemdetails: '&', 
        },
        templateUrl: 'list.html',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.label;
            scope.listItemClick=function(e){
                $(e.currentTarget).find('.next-items').slideToggle('fast');   
            }
             scope.moreitemdetails=function(name,type){
               //other code
             }
        }
    };
});
```

The call for directive is

```
<grocery-list array="items"></grocery-list>
```

This is the template file

```
<div ng-click="listItemClick($event)">
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                <span class="item-details">
                    {{array[0].Item}}

                </span>
                <span class="down-arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="next-items">
                <ul>
                    <li class="item" ng-repeat="list in array">
                        <div class="item-details" ng-click="moreitemdetails(list.Name,list.Type)">{{list.Item}}</div>
                    </li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Is there a way to get around?

I also would like to know the use of $location within another directive. Quoting the previous example (everythin is same except the directive definition and action in moreitemdetails() )

```
app.ui.directive('groceryList', ['$location', function(location){
return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                array: '=',
                listItemClick:'&',
                moreitemdetails: '&', 
            },
            templateUrl: 'list.html',

            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.label = attrs.label;
                scope.listItemClick=function(e){
                    $(e.currentTarget).find('.next-items').slideToggle('fast');   
                }
                 scope.moreitemdetails=function(name,type){
                   $location.path('/home/');
                 }
            }
        };
}]);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are creating a scope in your directive therefor you would have to access the controller using scope.$parent but this would be bad practice

Answer (score 0):

So by declaring

```
   scope: {
        array: '=',
        listItemClick:'&',
        moreitemdetails: '&', 
    },
```

you are creating an isolated scope for your directive. One solution might be to not declare this scope in your directive. This would mean that your ng-click="moreitemdetails(list.Name,list.Type) would trigger the function on your controllers scope.

Alternatively you could use an emit and listener. To do this, in your directive you could call:

```
scope.moreitemdetails=function(name,type){
   var deets = {
       name: name,
       type: type
    };
    scope.emit('moreitemdetails',deets)
}
```

Then in your various controllers you implement:

```
scope.$on('moreitemdetails',function(event,details){
// do some code with your name and type
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you would like to know about $location, if you could be a bit more specific I might be able to help a more.

Hope this helps in some way!

---

EDIT:
The directive without any scope declared would look like this:

```
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'list.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.label = attrs.label;
        scope.listItemClick=function(e){
            $(e.currentTarget).find('.next-items').slideToggle('fast');   
        }
         scope.moreitemdetails=function(name,type){
           //other code
         }
    }
};
```

Comment: I am not sure why you cannot just use ng-repeat and a generic function name.  Also reference ui-router as this would probably be a great asset for your application/site. (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: @mylescc One solution might be to not declare this scope in your directive. This would mean that your ng-click="moreitemdetails(list.Name,list.Type) would trigger the function on your controllers scope. --- Did you mean declaring a scope like, `code`scope: {
        array: '=',
        listItemClick:'&',
    } `code` but i am not sure that it will work. I have not tried the 'emit' solution.Will try and let you know. Then about $location, the code fragmented i posted in my first post was not working it was giving an error $location is not defined. Any help on that please?

Comment: @Misty - Hey misty, so what I meant is just not to include any declaration for a scope. So if you look at the edit to my answer above, I'm not declaring a scope. This will mean that your directive will inherit its parent scope, and so can call any functions its parent controller. Not sure I explained that great, but does that make sense?

Comment: @mylescc yes made sense :) Thanks. I have not tried the solution. Will do and catch you if needs more help :)